# Reciprocal Non-linear Hammerstein integral equation

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, operator-theory, integral-equations

I came across a problem that looks like a non-linear Hammerstein equation:
$$
\displaystyle y(t)= v(t)+\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\iota ts}}{y(s)}\mathrm{d}s
$$

I tried solving it by collocation method of finding the approximation $z(t)=\frac{1}{y(t)}$, which of course is an involution. Am i on the right track or is there some easy method to solve it.